# how would i make this embed the the roblox link

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

The code I use:

```js
const token = "";
let discord = require("discord.js");
client.on(`message`, (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.guild) return;
    if (message.content.startsWith("https://roblox.com")) {
        const msgLog = `[MESSAGE] [${message.guild.name}] [#${message.channel.name}] ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}: ${message.content}\n`;
        client.channels.get(`CHANNEL ID`).send(msgLog);
        return;
    }
});
client.login(token);
```

How would I make this have this embed and log in a certain channel

```js
const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.setTitle("64 Games")
.setColor(0x00AE86)
.setDescription("A Game Has been found!!!")
.setThumbnail("https://yagami.xyz/content/uploads/2018/11/discord-512-1.png")
.setTimestamp()
message.channel.send({embed})
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? What is the issue? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: yes when I try to put the embed in const msgLog = `[MESSAGE]  It errors

Comment: What does the error say?

Answer (score 1):

Operating under the assumption that you are using `discord.js` v12, there are two things you need to watch out for:

1. Getting the channel and sending the message

In your code, you send the message in a channel by doing:

```js
client.channels.get(`channel ID`).send(msgLog);
```

However, `client.channels` does not have the `get` method, you have to first use the `cache` property which then returns a Collection you can go through. So you should replace that with:

```js
client.channels.cache.get(`channel ID`).send(msgLog);
```

2. Setting up the embed

Your code declares the embed like so:

```js
const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
```

However, you need to lowercase the `Discord` (since you initially set `discord` to the `discord.js` module, and not `Discord`). In addition, `RichEmbed` is discontinued as of `discord.js` v12, you should use `MessageEmbed` instead, like this:

```js
const embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
```